How to bend or tilt UIView into a curve shape without disturbing its layout?
enter image description hereHow can we bend or tilt UIView as a curve shape?
Internally my UIView has few UI components
I tried using Bezierpaths by drawing, I could Draw curve shape my but my content is not fit in curve, It has its own frame
Not able to match UIView content in the same curve shape as if it shows as Curved UIView

post video of what you are trying to achieve...

Please review [ask]. You need to provide a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish. Include a "mock-up" image (or a couple of them) if necessary.
